# cv2.contourArea didn't get the right area

Tags: area

'1.png just has one contour'

```
img = cv2.imread('1.png')

retval,dst = cv2.threshold(img,120,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dst,cv2.RETR_EXTERANL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

print cv2.contourArea(contours[0],False)
```

The image just has one contour, then contours is a list.  When I change `contours[0]` to `contours[3]` or other numbers, there still have a area.  I have no ideas about the question, only one contour.

Why appear so many values?  It is the problem of the found thresh?  Need your help?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that what OpenCV considers to be a contour is only part of what you consider to be a contour.  In other words, OpenCV is splitting up your contour into pieces.  It's possible you could get the full area by adding the areas of the individual contours, but this method is not reliable.

Something you could try is [Image Morphology](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html).  Using this, you could "grow" the contours so that they overlap more, which would mean that the chance of OpenCV recognizing them as a single contour would be greater.

However, this method would result in a loss of precision.  Therefore, if you need an exact area, you will have to rely on other methods.  For complex geometries, this is not a simple task.

One more "quick and dirty" solution I've used is to create a fresh one-channel Mat (`Mat::zeros`), draw the contours filled with a color value of 255 (`drawContours`), and sum the contents (in c++ this is `cv::sum` and for you I *think* it's `cv2.sum`), then divide the result by 255.  This would get you the area in pixels, and would be more reliable than summing the areas of individual contours because it would account for overlap between them.